# How to set maxRequest in sfdx plugin? Error: exceeded max limit of concurrent call

Tags: jsforce, sfdx-plugin

We're developing an SFDX plugin aiming to help us with data migration between orgs.

SFDX plugins are using `jsforce`, as far as I've seen it's wrapped into `@salesforce/core` package. When writing using plain `jsforce`, I would instantiate my `connection` object passing `maxRequest` as a constructor parameter, as below:

```
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
                              loginUrl: config.targetOrg.loginUrl,
                              maxRequest: 1000});
```

However, in the SFDX plugin, the connection is given by the wrapper plugin out-of-the-box, the connection object that is already created:

```
const conn = this.org.getConnection();
```

When I do `console.log(conn);` I can see `maxRequest: 10`.

I don't see any public method that will allow me to change `maxRequest` property. I need to do it because upsert operation fails for me with arrays of records > 10 with the following error: `Error: Exceeded max limit of concurrent call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDIT]** Looks like the sfdx cli has updated [its dependency over jsforce](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/blob/develop/package.json#L48) to 1.9.3, so you should be able to use the core library directly now.

**[ORIGINAL ANSWER]** I had the same issue, but wasn't able to find a way to do it.

Also, for now 1 call = 1 record, so calling the API with 5000 records will send 5000 API calls, which isn't great. 
I tried changing the limit locally in the compiled JS of the CLI (just for the sake of trying), but I had some issues server side with too many calls received and some calls encountering timeout.

Starting v1.9, jsforce will make CRUD calls with a collection of records, instead of 1 call per record, so it's much better, see [here](https://jsforce.github.io/blog/posts/20180726-jsforce19-features.html).

I ended up importing jsforce directly, and creating a jsforce connection from the one of the cli like this:

```
conn = await getJsforceConnection(this.org.getConnection().getConnectionOptions());
```

This way, calling the CRUD operations will make use of jsforce 1.9 sObjects collections.

You can have a look to the small helper [here](https://github.com/texei/texei-sfdx-plugin/blob/master/src/shared/jsforceHelper.ts), and the code using it [here](https://github.com/texei/texei-sfdx-plugin/blob/master/src/commands/texei/data/import.ts#L47).

Lastly, I created an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues/141) on the CLI's repo to ask moving the jsforce dependency to 1.9.